# weblogic datasource overloads when stats running on Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, datasource, weblogic-10.x

We have had a problem when stats are running (Oracle 11.2.3) that our datasources are becoming overloaded, there is not much activity on the web server at the time, it seems that even the test connection can cause the overload, weblogic version is 11G(10.3.0).
We have just moved the database server to new H/W and upgraded from 10G. None of these problems existed pre upgrade.

Stats need to run on this server at some stage and it is an externally facing system so no time is a good time - we think we have picked the slowest times. Anybody come across something like this before?

Comment: Have you checked the number of connections supported by your database? you datasource pool size should be less than the connections supported by your database.

Comment: Thanks, I will get the DBA to check now, corrected weblogic version also above

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out, the stats were doing a full deletion before they gathered - This in turn was causing bad plans to be created in the SGA which was causing normal running queries to become long running which in turn was having knock ons to datasources - it was difficult to see as the stats job had normally finished by the time we got to investigate. Solution is to remove the deletion, also flush the SGA to ensure that there are no bad plan left in there. 
We are also following up on the supported connections from the comment Manish made to ensure we have some room with no of connections.